# Unable to open Runner.xwworkspace file from project directory

Tags: xcode, flutter

While opening runner.xwworkspace from flutter project ios directory I am getting an error file does not exist.

Also while building it from xcode i am getting error ==> /bin/sh: /packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Did you change anything in your iOS project? If not then I can recommend recreating the iOS project by running `flutter create` again e.g.:

Go to the root of your project and remove ios directory and then recreate the project:

```
rm -rf ./ios
flutter create .
```

Check also the output from `flutter doctor`.